# How to design one-to-many relationship tables considering update operation?

Tags: mysql

I may appoint some specific receivers when new a notice. So I design one-to-many tables named `notice` and `receiver`:

```
mysql> select * from notice;
+----+-------+                         
| id | title |                                
+----+-------+                                                                                                        
|  1 | demo  |                                                                                                        
+----+-------+ 

mysql> select * from receiver;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | notice_id | name   |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | calvin |
|  2 |         1 | john   |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

When I update the notice, the receivers might be updated too(Assuming the receivers should be updated to *calvin* and *Jack*). My current solution is deleting all receivers related to the notice and inserting the new ones. Is there any better and higher-performance solution? I can redesign the tables if it's necessary.

Comment: it looks like you want a message queue, not a sql database.

Comment: @danblack, the notice and related data could be save as draft, so I need a persistent storage.